# Node.js - Using eventemitters with decorators and Typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, decorator, eventemitter

I am attempting to create a decorator that will fire an event each time the function under it starts and then ends. I have created a class that extends EventEmitter:

```
class OnActionExecuting extends EventEmitter {
    constructor(handler) {
        super();
        this.on('onExecuting', handler);
        this.emit('onExecuting');
    }
}
```

I can create a factory function for use in the decorator:

```
function onActionExecuting(handler) {
    return () => new OnActionExecuting(handler);
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
class Test {
    @onActionExecuting(() => console.log('started...'))
    public test() {
        console.log('running...')
    }
}
```

This outputs as expected like so (though I don't think it is doing what I originally thought):

```
starting...
running...
```

First, my problem is how to create a decorator for that triggers *after* the function below it completes. So, something like this:

```
class Test {
    @onActionExecuting(() => console.log('started...'))
    @onActionComplete(() => console.log('finished!'))
    public test() {
        console.log('running...')
    }
}
```

would have an output like this:

```
starting...
running...
finished!
```

Second, I feel like I am not using these correctly at all. I am new to Typescript and still learning the intricacies of vanilla javascript. The closest thing I have experience with like this are .NET attributes (and how similar those are, I am still not sure).

Does anyone know how to achieve the effect I am going for? Or can anyone point me to resources in combining Typescript, Nodejs, and decorators?